# VBA Macro Loop unable to copy numbers from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this For loop vba code wherein I have a summary sheet (Stock Strategy sheet) where it summarizes all the numbers I need from different sheets.

I have grouped the codes that suppose to copy the numbers through comments for everyone's reference.

Anyway, what seems to be not working is the "VOLUME" portion. The other two (ADX and Close) is working perfectly but the "Volume" is not. Which is weird because the code execution is the same with the other two.

```
Private Sub pback()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wsx As Worksheet
lastrow = Sheets("Stocks Strategy").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsx = Sheets("Stocks Strategy")

For i = 3 To lastrow

'Close
wsx.Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Value
wsx.Cells(i, 5).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value
wsx.Cells(i, 6).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("E1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0).Value


'Volume - not sure why its not working
wsx.Cells(i, 13).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("S1048576").End(xlUp).Value
wsx.Cells(i, 14).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("S1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value
wsx.Cells(i, 15).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("S1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0).Value

'ADX
wsx.Cells(i, 8).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("Q1048576").End(xlUp).Value
wsx.Cells(i, 9).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("Q1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Value
wsx.Cells(i, 10).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("Q1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(-2, 0).Value


Next i
End Sub
```

Screenshots of my sheets:

**Stocks Strategy**

*(Column A represents the Sheet Names where it will get the numbers "Close", "ADX" & "Volume") )*

[image]

**Sample Source Sheets** *(sheets where Stocks Strategy will get the numbers)*

[image: image here]

**Just a note:** All the sheets are in the same workbook.

Would any one point out what's wrong? I would appreciate if anyone could also suggest a better way of coding this task?

Comment: Are you sure you have no other code running after the posted code which is clearing the values from column M and N again?  Try putting a breakpoint on the `Cells(i, 8).Value = ...` line and see what the sheet looks like once you get there.  But be careful, your code is writing to whatever the active sheet is, so make sure you always switch back to that sheet (I assume it is meant to be the "Stocks Strategy" sheet that is active) prior to continuing execution.

Comment: I am sure that no other codes running. no other codes clearing the column M and N. I have added a break point and it really not writing what it suppose to input. I also have modified It to wsx.Cells(i, 13).Value = Sheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value).Range("S1048576").End(xlUp).Value to make it specific. but I still get the same result. nothing is being written.

Comment: Based on the screenshots, it is correctly doing the `wsx.Cells(i, 15).Value = ...` statement, so it is just the last and second-last values that is causing an issue, which is .... **weird**.  FWIW, I just created some dummy data and it worked OK for me.

Comment: Isn't it just because of hidden columns ? The volume is in column (i,19) not (i,8) ? /// My bad.... looked too fast

Comment: You don't have any events active, do you? Such as `Worksheet_Change` or something along those lines? Regardless, it wouldn't hurt to disable events at the top of the procedure and see what happens.

Comment: I am not sure why or how. but when I restarted my excel, everything worked properly. I didn't edit anything. :D not sure what happens. anyway, thank you every one who made an effort to take a look at my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing sticks out as being wrong in your code. In any case, does the below also not work for you?

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub pback()

    Dim i As long
Dim LastRow as long

    Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet 
    Set DestinationSheet = workSheets("Stocks Strategy")

    lastrow = DestinationSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim SourceSheet as Worksheet
    Dim LastCellInColumn as range

    For i = 3 To lastrow 

    Set SourceSheet = worksheets(wsx.Cells(i, 1).Value)

    With sourcesheet

    'Close '
    Set LastCellInColumn = .cells(.rows.count,"E").end(xlup)

    If LastCellInColumn.row > 2 then
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 4).Value = LastCellInColumn.Value
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 5).Value =  lastcellincolumn.offset(-1,0).Value
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value = lastcellincolumn.Offset(-2, 0).Value

    Else
    Msgbox("Last cell on worksheet " & .name & " detected as being on row " & LastCellInColumn.row)
    End if

    'Volume - not sure why its not working'

    Set LastCellInColumn = .cells(.rows.count,"S").end(xlup)

    If LastCellInColumn.row > 2 then
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = LastCellInColumn.Value
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 14).Value = LastCellInColumn.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 15).Value = LastCellInColumn.Offset(-2, 0).Value

    Else
    Msgbox("Last cell on worksheet " & .name & " detected as being on row " & LastCellInColumn.row)
    End if


    'ADX'

    Set LastCellInColumn = .cells(.rows.count,"Q").end(xlup)

    If LastCellInColumn.row > 2 then

    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value = LastCellInColumn.Value
    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 9).Value = LastCellInColumn.Offset(-1, 0).Value

    DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 10).Value = LastCellInColumn.Offset(-2, 0).Value

    Else
    Msgbox("Last cell on worksheet " & .name & " detected as being on row " & LastCellInColumn.row)
    End if

    End with

    Set Lastcellincolumn = nothing
    Set Sourcesheet = nothing

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: you are using `SourceSheet` getting the `lastrow` 2-4 rows before you actualy `Dim` it and `Set` it, this will result with a run-time error

Comment: True, `SourceSheet` should have been `DestinationSheet`. Can't test as am on mobile.

Comment: So next time, at least mention in your answer that it's (UnTested)